# Is this the correct way of translating Java interface into Scala?

Tags: java, oop, scala, inheritance, traits

I am starting to learn Scala and I will do a simple cross compiler.

I will support a small set of instructions like print.

Note: the code snippets are not tested or compiled.
Here is what I would do in JAVA.

```
public interface Compiler{
 String getPrintInstruction();
}

public class JavaCompiler implements Compiler{
 public String getPrintInstruction(){
  return "System.out.print(arg0);"
 }
}

public class ScalaCompiler implements Compiler{
 public String getPrintInstruction(){
  return "print(arg0);"
 }
}
```

Is the snippet below the correct *"Scala way*"?

```
trait Compiler {
  var printInstruction: String
}
class JavaCompiler extends Compiler {
  var printInstruction = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}
class ScalaCompiler extends Compiler {
  var printInstruction = "print(arg0);"
}
```

**EDIT:**

I will move my second question to a new thread.

Comment: The variable that you declared is not defined until you give it a value. Try to extend Compiler without giving a value for printInstruction. It is not really a redeclaration as you can see if you give it a non-string value like 42.

Comment: I don't understand, please bear with me :), it seems defined because if I give it the value 42 the compiler writes: overriding variable printInstruction in trait Compiler of type String;  variable printInstruction has incompatible type

Comment: You get the error in your variable _definition_ because the variable _declaration_ in the super class has an incompatible type. We declare a variable printInstruction with type String and we define the value of that value to be for example "hi". Contrary to java you can't leave out the definition and get a default (null or 0). In that regard the 'var x: String' is abstract like a method is abstract; however that word is not used, it is undefined.

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other that much but I get I only pasted it to show you that the compiler knew it was a string and therefore not undefined. Thanks for the explanation though I have started a new thread because this is to long for the comments field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 1:1 mapping, those `var`s should be changed to `def`s.

```
trait Compiler {
  def printInstruction: String
}

class JavaCompiler extends Compiler {
  def printInstruction = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}

class ScalaCompiler extends Compiler {
  def printInstruction = "print(arg0);"
}
```

`def` declares a method. When you don't provide an implementation, it becomes an abstract method.

**EDIT:**

The technique used here is a valid and useful technique. Alternatively you could use one of the following two techniques to model your problem.

1) Discriminated unions. (aka sum types.)

Refer to [this excellent article](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/functional-scala-algebraic-datatypes-sum-and-product-types/) to learn about this concept. This is how your example would probably look like when modeled this way:

```
sealed trait Compiler {
  def printInstruction: String = this match {
    case JavaCompiler => "System.out.print(arg0);"
    case ScalaCompiler => "print(arg0);"
  }
}

case object JavaCompiler extends Compiler
case object ScalaCompiler extends Compiler
```

2) Type class pattern.

[Here](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2010/06/implicit-tricks-type-class-pattern.html) is a great post by Daniel Sobral on this topic. You can dig up a few more by googling the terms type-class, pattern, Scala, implicits etc. This is how your code might look like if the problem's modeled with type class pattern:

```
trait Compiler[C] {
  def printInstruction(c: C): String
}

case object JavaCompiler

implicit object JavaCompilerIsCompiler extends Compiler[JavaCompiler.type] {
  def printInstruction(c: JavaCompiler.type): String = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}

case object ScalaCompiler

implicit object ScalaCompilerIsCompiler extends Compiler[ScalaCompiler.type] {
  def printInstruction(c: ScalaCompiler.type) = "print(arg0);"
}
```

For your problem, the original approach and the discriminated unions approach seem to be the best modeling solutions.

Comment: Or at least to `val` instead of `var`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want an 1:1 mapping I wanted the best Scala way to solve my "problem". I am trying to learn the Scala way and not just Scala syntax with Java mindset.

Comment: @Farmor, the technique being used here is used widely in Scala as well. Not all techniques from Java become obsolete simply because they are used in Java.

Comment: @Farmor, alternatively you could use discriminated unions. Let me expand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Why do I have to re declare the variable one more time in the class when I have declared it in the trait?*

Because you declared the signature of the method `printInstruction` but you did not say what it did. In a `class`, as it is not an `abstract class` all functions should be defined. 
By the way, you could have defined `printInstruction` directly in the `trait Compiler`if it is supposed to do the same in every implementation.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand Scala but isn't var an variable and not a method? Or does Scala treat variables as methods? printInstruction shouldn't be a method but a String field with a different String for each compiler.

Comment: I think that what misleaded us it that you wrote `getPrintInstruction()`, the parenthesis were a sign that you wrote a method (in java it is a method). So a variable is different than a function because you can set and get the variable, basically you cannot set the function, you can use it to "create" the result.

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic way is to use a `def` for abstract properties, and a `val` for concrete read-only properties.  Under the *Uniform Access Principle*, a `val` can be used to implement a method:

```
trait Compiler {
  def printInstruction: String
}

class JavaCompiler extends Compiler {
  val printInstruction = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}

class ScalaCompiler extends Compiler {
  val printInstruction = "print(arg0);"
}
```