# Why do I have to redefine an already defined variable in a trait when extending in Scala

Tags: scala

Why do I have to do

```
trait Compiler {
  var printInstruction: String
}
class JavaCompiler extends Compiler {
  var printInstruction = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}
```

instead of

```
trait Compiler {
  var printInstruction: String
}
class JavaCompiler extends Compiler {
  printInstruction = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}
```

when

```
trait Compiler {
  var printInstruction: String
  def printInstruction: String
}
```

gives compile error.

Comment: Shouldn't you write `override var printInstruction = "System.out.print(arg0);"`? You are overriding property in JavaCompiler

Comment: He can but it's not mandatory, as `printInstruction` is abstract, it can be defined without an òverride`modifier. Some consider it's a good practice to add `override`others believe it a bit useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you don't initialize the variable in trait `Compiler`. It means that you expect that anyone who extends `Compile` defines something *that behaves* like a variable.

For example the following is valid:

```
class Example extends Compiler {

   var _printInstruction = "foo"

   def pritnInstruction = "I don't care about setter"

   def pritnInstruction_=(pi: String) = _printInstruction = pi
}
```

If you want to be able to use

```
class JavaCompiler extends Compiler {
  printInstruction = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}
```

Then initialize your var in the `Compiler`trait:

```
trait Compiler {
  var printInstruction: String = _
}
```

Comment: I'm not the author of this question, but may I ask some explanation? What does mean underscore in `var printInstruction: String = _`?

Comment: _ means that you initialize the variable with a default value, depending of the type of the variable `var x: Int = _` leads to x = 0; `var y: String = _`leads to y = null, and so on. The same as implicit initialization in java. It's most of the time a bad practice.

Comment: And why was error when var is defined without default value? It was treated as abstract/unimplemented?

Comment: That's it. Wihout it, you leave the implementation up to the concrete class, it can either define a var or define a setter/getter pair

Answer (score 0):

Overriding vars is generally not something you want to do. If you want something that *behaves* like a `var`, and may even be one, you do this:

```
trait Compiler {
  def printInstruction: String
  def printInstruction_=(s: String): Unit
}

class JavaCompiler {
  var printInstructions = "System.out.print(arg0);"
}
```

Somehow I don't think that's what you intended. So... what don't you explain what you actually intend to accomplish, so we can better advise on how to do it?

Comment: Its a spin of from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033253/is-this-the-correct-way-of-translating-java-interface-into-scala/9034680#9034680 there we have the best solution to the original problem. This was just a question of why the compiler didn't chose to define var for me if left undefined.